# Quotient by the intersection of maximal subgroups in a free group.

Tags: group-theory, simple-groups

My question is (a modification of) the following:

> Let $N=\cap M$, where $M$ is maximal normal of finite index in the free group $G=F_2$. Then what is the group $G/N$?

Currently written, this is a flawed question - $N$ is necessarily trivial, because of cyclic groups of prime order, hence $F_2/N=F_2$. So...having thought about this a bit, I am pretty sure the following is the question I want to ask (as simple groups are generated by an involution and...some other element):

> Let $N=\cap M$, where $M$ is maximal normal of finite index in the free product $G=\mathbb{Z}_2\ast\mathbb{Z}$ and the group $G/M$ is non-cyclic. Then what is the group $G/N$?

A different, but related question is:

> Let $N=\cap_I M_i$, where $M_i$ is maximal normal of finite index in the free product $G=\mathbb{Z}_2\ast\mathbb{Z}$, the group $G/M_i$ is non-cyclic and $G/M_i\cong G/M_j$ for all $i, j\in I$. Then what is the group $G/N$?

Comment: You seem to be talking about maximal normal subgroups $M$ rather than maximal subgroups.

Comment: For the first question, I would guess that $N$ is trivial. For the second, when $S=G/M_i$ is finite, $G/N$ is a direct product of a finite number of copies of the simple group $S$. For example, for $S=A_5$, we get $G/N \cong A_5^3$.

Comment: @Derek Yes, sorry, I was missing "normal". I was also missing "finite index", which I have edited in.